# Can a Rogue/Cleric multiclass doing sneak attack or using Rogue powers with an Radiant enchanted weapon?

Tags: dnd-4e, cleric, rogue, sneak-attack

I'm playing a Rogue in D&D 4.0 and I multiclass to Cleric in order to take the Radiant Servant Paragon Path.

I have some questions about if some rogue features or powers still applies when using cleric powers.

Here I have some examples:

1. Using the "Weapon of the Gods" cleric power, that gives 1d6 radiant damage to the target weapon until the end of the encounter. Can still apply my sneak attack when I have combat advantage and attack with the "enchanted" weapon?
2. Same of above but using a rogue power that buffs the enemy with some affliction (prone, blind, stun, dazed)...Can I use this power with the "enchanted" weapon? Can still the weapon doing the radiant damage?
3. When using a cleric power that involves the use of the weapon  to do a melee attack (for example: Nimbus of Doom), can still doing the sneak attack damage if I have combat advantage against the target?

Answer (score 13):

to answer your questions in order.

1. Yes. Weapon of the Gods will work extremely well with your rogue powers. It will even add the radiant keyword to them. This is especially useful when dealing with undead. Your weapon remains a light blade/crossbow/short bow so you can definitely continue to inflict sneak attack damage.
2. Yes. The status affects inflicted do not conflict with the damage type. In fact the damage type is added to the damage type on the power (for instance if the power deals necrotic, it would also deal radiant).
3. Yes. The full version (not hybrid) of sneak attack requires you to hit with a specified weapon, not that it be a rogue power, so cleric powers are great (provided your valid rogue weapon is the implement or the weapon for the power). To add to this, the hybrid version of sneak attack (labeled "Sneak Attack (Hybrid)") does require you to use it with rogue powers and would not work in this case.

So yes, your planned build works just fine with the main class as rogue and a multi-class to cleric taking a cleric PP works just fine.

Comment: Re #3: Sneak Attack reads: "When you make an attack with a light blade, a hand crossbow, a shortbow, or a sling and hit an enemy granting combat advantage to you..." so you are exactly correct.

Comment: correct on that Rogue Hybrid (labeled with Sneak attack (hybrid)) which reads: This class feature functions as the rogue class feature, except that you can deal the extra damage only when you hit with a rogue power or a rogue paragon path power (Which btw sucks if you are forced to do a melee basic attack)